# C# highlight current char in textbox while typing

Tags: c#, char, highlight

I wrote this code when i click or focus on text box selection char is highlight
but while i typing(Edit) highlight can't show(Textbox have Default text)

```
        textBox1.GotFocus += textbox1_OnFocus;

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.'))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // only allow one decimal point
        if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.SelectionStart;
        textBox1.SelectionLength = 1;

    }

     private void textbox1_OnFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
        textBox1.SelectionStart = 0 ;
        textBox1.SelectionLength = 1;

    }

    private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.SelectionStart);
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.SelectionStart;
        textBox1.SelectionLength = 1;
    }
```

how can i edit my code to get my correct answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wrote this it work but i think this is not good way

```
        private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.SelectionStart;
        textBox1.SelectionLength = 1;
    }
```